# Javascript communication between two web applications on different domains

Tags: javascript, drupal, cross-domain, jsonp

I have a web app, which is launched in a new pop-up window when a customer clicks a link on a Drupal web content page.

When the user reaches a certain page in the web application's workflow, I want to send a message to the (still open) Drupal page and pass it some information (like where in the workflow I'm up to).

When the Drupal website receives this 'message', it calls some javascript on its end to update the currently displayed page content.

So basically, a way to execute Javascript on one domain, from a Javascript function in another domain.

I have control over both the Drupal site and the web application so any javascript which needs to be deployed on either end isn't an issue. **But note that the two sites are on different domains, so I need to implement something that will work cross-domain**

I am not sure how to implement this, I have considered JSON-P so far.

Answer (score 0):

Both your web apps are running at client-side, so you don't need to ask to server about how to contact with the window that you already opened.

So, to save time and effort, make a directly comunication between the windows at client-side.

To send a message to another html page, you need to first keep in a variable the window opened, as bellow:

```
// This code is inside the html file that open 
// the drupal site.
var windowOpened = window.open("drupalUrl.html");
```

but, at drupalUrl.html you need to create a global function, so you can call like this:

```
windowOpened.globalFunction(param1, param2);
```

As I said, inside the drupalUrl.html you need to create a function:

```
function globalFunction(param1, param2){
    //show your message
}
```

Comment: I usually use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) instead of a "global function" to send messages between pages on different domains.